# Printing a gif from a variable with php

Tags: php, xml

I am experimenting with the Endicia shipping label server.  The sample code below allows me to get a USPS label from their test server.  How would I display the image that is being returned.  Right now the print_r function (if un-commented out) does print out the array contents of what appears to be an image.

```
<?php

$strGetLabelURL = "https://www.envmgr.com/LabelService/EwsLabelService.asmx/GetPostageLabelXML";

$request = '<LabelRequest ImageFormat="GIF" Test="YES">
     <RequesterID>abcd</RequesterID>
     <AccountID>123456</AccountID>
     <PassPhrase>samplePassPhrase</PassPhrase>
     <MailClass>FIRST</MailClass>
     <DateAdvance>0</DateAdvance>
     <WeightOz>1</WeightOz>
     <Stealth>FALSE</Stealth>
     <Services InsuredMail="OFF" SignatureConfirmation="OFF" />
     <Value>0</Value>
     <Description>Sample Label</Description>
     <PartnerCustomerID>12345ABCD</PartnerCustomerID>
     <PartnerTransactionID>6789EFGH</PartnerTransactionID>
     <ToName>Ben Franklin</ToName>
     <ToCompany>United States Postal Service</ToCompany>
     <ToAddress1>12345 Main Street</ToAddress1>
     <ToCity>Camas</ToCity>
     <ToState>WA</ToState>
     <ToPostalCode>98607</ToPostalCode>
     <ToPhone>2025551212</ToPhone>
     <FromName>Technical Support</FromName>
     <FromCompany>DYMO Endicia</FromCompany>
     <ReturnAddress1>385 Sherman Ave.</ReturnAddress1>
     <FromCity>Palo Alto</FromCity>
     <FromState>CA</FromState>
     <FromPostalCode>94306</FromPostalCode>
     <FromZIP4>1864</FromZIP4>
     <FromPhone>8005763279</FromPhone>
     </LabelRequest>';

 $params = array('http' => array(
     'method' => 'POST',
     'content' => 'labelRequestXML='.$request,
     'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

 $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
 $fp = fopen($strGetLabelURL, 'rb', false, $ctx);

 if (!$fp) 
 {
     print "Problem with $strGetLabelURL";
 }

 $response = stream_get_contents($fp);

 if ($response === false) 
 {
     print "Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg";
 }

 print_r($response);
?>
```

Comment: What is the content of $response?

Comment: Is the image's blob an array element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to load the XML, extract the image data, then put it in an image:

```
$sxml = Simplexml_load_string( $response );
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $sxml->Base64LabelImage . '">';
```

Comment: Awesome... thanks.  I added extra options to suppress warnings...   Simplexml_load_string( $response , NULL, LIBXML_NOWARNING ); and it works great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Endicia solution but I think it's quite similar to UPS.
From the XML you send one can see that you ask for the label in GIF format.
I suppose that in the response you have an element named `<LabelImage>` or something similar. You need to extract the value that is between the opening and the closing tag and use below to print it on your browser:

`echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $value . '" alt="" />';`